# How to split faces where they intersect

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I am working in edit mode in Blender 2.8.

There is a volume through which I constructed 2 planes. Now I want to remove the excess parts. To do so, I think I need to split the faces where they intersect.

See the image: I want to remove all parts marked with a red cross.

To do this, I think I just need to figure out how to create the edges with the green dotted lines, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Maybe another way to explain this: if you look at both the horizontal and vertical line in the front, these do not intersect. Although they are in the same plane, there is no vertex where they cross and I can't find any button to perform this action.

[image: Trying to remove a small corner from a larger volume]

---

Solutions I tried:

**Rip apart the faces**. In the screenshot I'm trying to adjust one of the faces, but this doesn't really merge the top edge with the horizontal face, which is what I'm looking for. Or maybe I'm not using the tool correctly.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). There was a [very similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/162129/78972) a few days ago. Let us know if it helps in your case :).

Comment: Thanks @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ that fixed it. What I did was: Face context menu: Intersect (Knife) and select "self intersect". This is exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to create an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Happy to help :). I'll just link the two questions, so others can find it. No need to post an answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Go into face select mode and select the faces you want to delete then press x so the delete menu will appear then select face to delete the face and to again close the open face go to edge select mode and select the edges you want to close and press f to make the face.

Comment: The problem is that there is no edge to create the new face. In my original screenshot: the green dotted lines are not edges.

Comment: Hmm, I miss understanding the problem. Yes, in this case, you can use the knife tool to make the cuts or edges then you can apply this technique to remove the faces.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to completely separate the faces while leaving them all intact, you can select the edges shared by the faces and press V to rip them apart.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what I was expecting. I will add a screenshot to my original post to explain